# Multiplatform development options

Tags: iphone, android, flash, cross-platform

I have an application (actually a game) that I'm close to starting work on for iOS and the web, however I'd like to DRY up my code bases as much as possible so that I don't have to maintain so many aspects for platform portability.  So essentially my two requirements are to run on iOS and the web, but I wouldn't mind it if I could also deploy it for Android as well.

What options exist?

If possible, which I am doubting at the moment, I have considered using Cappuccino (http://cappuccino.org/) to build out the app and then utilize NimbleKit for iOS compilation.  Any ideas if this is possible?

What would work better if anything?  Are there any frameworks in particular that would scale across platforms and mobile devices well + allow it to easily run on the web?

Also, Flash comes to mind, would that perhaps be best if developed properly such that it will compile over and not utilize non-compatible iOS functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recently released monkey development framework deploys to both iOS and Flash:
http://www.monkeycoder.co.nz/

It's so new that I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, but it has a great pedigree: the creator made Blitz3D and BlitzMax before, and those were great game development tools.

That said, I would strongly recommend a combo like Corona for iOS and Flash for web, so that you're using optimal tools for each platform.

Comment: This looks absolutely fascinating re: Monkey.  Thanks for sharing.  I am very concerned about being able to access the Apple apis for kits such as Store Kit and so forth.

It doesn't appear that options such as Flash Packager will be able to fill that need.  Hitherto I was deeply considering utilizing just Flash across the board as it I've seen some amazing development done with that on the iOS, however for now it appears utilizing things like Store Kit won't be possible.  Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Unity 3D. Works for iOs, Android, Web, Mac, and Pc. Not free for the mobile platforms, but it's worth a try.

Comment: The only problem is that while it "works" on the web, the penetration of the Unity player is poor and people have shown resistance to installing it.  Also, the current zeitgeist of "plugins are evil" perpetuated by Apple and the web standards community make the future adoption of "new" plugins like Unity's web player look quite grim.  Shame.  However, Unity recently announced plans to output .swf files, taking advantage of Adobe's brand new GPU-accelerated 3D APIs.  Obviously this isn't out yet but if/when they succeed at it Unity could be the clear "winner" in cross-platform development.

Comment: True, but it still works quite well on mobile platforms and desktop.

Comment: That it does.  It's a neat tool that I like more and more, the more I use it.  I'm just being realistic about the current climate.  Also one thing to note is that the Android support in Unity isn't a fully-baked as the other platforms quite yet.  Hopefully this will improve over time.

Comment: Which is why I think Flash is a good candidate. People expect most games on the web to be Flash. Penetration is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/) (it's free). You can use javascript and HTML5 to build your game and it can be compiled for iOS and Android. Since you will be using web standards to code, your application can be deployed for the web with few (or no) modifications.

You can use [this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/golingo-a-great-titanium-mobile-web-game-open-sourced-for-you) project as a start point.

Comment: Using web standards for developing games sounds like a horrifying concept to me.

Comment: I have to disagree. You can build a multi-platform (including iOS) game using [ImpactJS](http://impactjs.com/), for instance, which is based on HTML5. You code using JS, the same language used to code in Unity and almost the same used to code in Flash.